# R package long time to install - Source or Binary type

Tags: r, installation, stringr, r-package, stringi

Am trying to install a package called `stringi` using the below command

`install.packages("stringi")`

Though it doesn't throw any error message but the installation is not over yet.

I see lot of messages in my console screen which keeps running for more than 45 minutes

```
> install.packages("stringi")
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/Aks/Documents/R/win-library/3.6’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)

  There is a binary version available but the source version is later:
        binary source needs_compilation
stringi  1.4.6  1.5.3              TRUE

installing the source package ‘stringi’

trying URL 'http://mirror.las.iastate.edu/CRAN/src/contrib/stringi_1.5.3.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 7293930 bytes (7.0 MB)
downloaded 7.0 MB

* installing *source* package 'stringi' ...
** package 'stringi' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
** libs

*** arch - i386
C:/Rtools/mingw_32/bin/g++  -std=gnu++11 -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-36~1.2/include" -DNDEBUG -I. -Iicu61/ -Iicu61/unicode -Iicu61/common -Iicu61/i18n -DU_STATIC_IMPLEMENTATION -DU_COMMON_IMPLEMENTATION -DU_I18N_IMPLEMENTATION -DUCONFIG_USE_LOCAL -DU_TOOLUTIL_IMPLEMENTATION -DNDEBUG -DWINVER=0x0600 -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0600 -DU_USE_STRTOD_L=0         -O2 -Wall  -mtune=generic -c stri_pad.cpp -o stri_pad.o
C:/Rtools/mingw_32/bin/g++  -std=gnu++11 -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-36~1.2/include" -DNDEBUG -I. -Iicu61/ -Iicu61/unicode -Iicu61/common -Iicu61/i18n -DU_STATIC_IMPLEMENTATION -DU_COMMON_IMPLEMENTATION -DU_I18N_IMPLEMENTATION -DUCONFIG_USE_LOCAL -DU_TOOLUTIL_IMPLEMENTATION -DNDEBUG -DWINVER=0x0600 -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0600 -DU_USE_STRTOD_L=0         -O2 -Wall  -mtune=generic -c stri_container_utf16.cpp -o stri_container_utf16.o
C:/Rtools/mingw_32/bin/g++  -std=gnu++11 -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-36~1.2/include" -DNDEBUG -I. -Iicu61/ -Iicu61/unicode -Iicu61/common -Iicu61/i18n -DU_STATIC_IMPLEMENTATION -DU_COMMON_IMPLEMENTATION -DU_I18N_IMPLEMENTATION -DUCONFIG_USE_LOCAL -DU_TOOLUTIL_IMPLEMENTATION -DNDEBUG -DWINVER=0x0600 -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0600 -DU_USE_STRTOD_L=0         -O2 -Wall  -mtune=generic -c stri_search_regex_split.cpp -o stri_search_regex_split.o
C:/Rtools/mingw_32/bin/g++  -std=gnu++11 -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-36~1.2/include" -DNDEBUG -I. -Iicu61/ -Iicu61/unicode -Iicu61/common -Iicu61/i18n -DU_STATIC_IMPLEMENTATION -DU_COMMON_IMPLEMENTATION -DU_I18N_IMPLEMENTATION -DUCONFIG_USE_LOCAL -DU_TOOLUTIL_IMPLEMENTATION -DNDEBUG -DWINVER=0x0600 -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0600 -DU_USE_STRTOD_L=0         -O2 -Wall  -mtune=generic -c stri_uloc.cpp -o stri_uloc.o
C:/Rtools/mingw_32/bin/g++  -std=gnu++11 -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-36~1.2/include" -DNDEBUG -I. -Iicu61/ -Iicu61/unicode -Iicu61/common -Iicu61/i18n -DU_STATIC_IMPLEMENTATION -DU_COMMON_IMPLEMENTATION -DU_I18N_IMPLEMENTATION -DUCONFIG_USE_LOCAL -DU_TOOLUTIL_IMPLEMENTATION -DNDEBUG -DWINVER=0x0600 -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0600 -DU_USE_STRTOD_L=0         -O2 -Wall  -mtune=generic -c stri_wrap.cpp -o stri_wrap.o
C:/Rtools/mingw_32/bin/g++  -std=gnu++11 -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-36~1.2/include" -DNDEBUG -I. -Iicu61/ -Iicu61/unicode -Iicu61/common -Iicu61/i18n -DU_STATIC_IMPLEMENTATION -DU_COMMON_IMPLEMENTATION -DU_I18N_IMPLEMENTATION -DUCONFIG_USE_LOCAL -DU_TOOLUTIL_IMPLEMENTATION -DNDEBUG -DWINVER=0x0600 -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0600 -DU_USE_STRTOD_L=0         -O2 -Wall  -mtune=generic -c stri_container_listutf8.cpp -o stri_container_listutf8.o
C:/Rtools/mingw_32/bin/g++  -std=gnu++11 -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-36~1.2/include" -DNDEBUG -I. -Iicu61/ -Iicu61/unicode -Iicu61/common -Iicu61/i18n -DU_STATIC_IMPLEMENTATION -DU_COMMON_IMPLEMENTATION -DU_I18N_IMPLEMENTATION -DUCONFIG_USE_LOCAL -DU_TOOLUTIL_IMPLEMENTATION -DNDEBUG -DWINVER=0x0600 -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0600 -DU_USE_STRTOD_L=0         -O2 -Wall  -mtune=generic -c stri_search_class_count.cpp -o stri_search_class_count.o
C:/Rtools/mingw_32/bin/g++  -std=gnu++11 -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-36~1.2/include" -DNDEBUG -I. -Iicu61/ -Iicu61/unicode -Iicu61/common -Iicu61/i18n -DU_STATIC_IMPLEMENTATION -DU_COMMON_IMPLEMENTATION -DU_I18N_IMPLEMENTATION -DUCONFIG_USE_LOCAL -DU_TOOLUTIL_IMPLEMENTATION -DNDEBUG -DWINVER=0x0600 -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0600 -DU_USE_STRTOD_L=0         -O2 -Wall  -mtune=generic -c stri_trans_casemap.cpp -o stri_trans_casemap.o
C:/Rtools/mingw_32/bin/g++  -std=gnu++11 -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-36~1.2/include" -DNDEBUG -I. -Iicu61/ -Iicu61/unicode -Iicu61/common -Iicu61/i18n -DU_STATIC_IMPLEMENTATION -DU_COMMON_IMPLEMENTATION -DU_I18N_IMPLEMENTATION -DUCONFIG_USE_LOCAL -DU_TOOLUTIL_IMPLEMENTATION -DNDEBUG -DWINVER=0x0600 -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0600 -DU_USE_STRTOD_L=0         -O2 -Wall  -mtune=generic -c stri_search_class_trim.cpp -o stri_search_class_trim.o
C:/Rtools/mingw_32/bin/g++  -std=gnu++11 -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-36~1.2/include" -DNDEBUG -I. -Iicu61/ -Iicu61/unicode -Iicu61/common -Iicu61/i18n -DU_STATIC_IMPLEMENTATION -DU_COMMON_IMPLEMENTATION -DU_I18N_IMPLEMENTATION -DUCONFIG_USE_LOCAL -DU_TOOLUTIL_IMPLEMENTATION -DNDEBUG -DWINVER=0x0600 -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0600 -DU_USE_STRTOD_L=0         -O2 -Wall  -mtune=generic -c stri_trans_normalization.cpp -o stri_trans_normalization.o
C:/Rtools/mingw_32/bin/g++  -std=gnu++11 -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-36~1.2/include" -DNDEBUG -I. -Iicu61/ -Iicu61/unicode -Iicu61/common -Iicu61/i18n -DU_STATIC_IMPLEMENTATION -DU_COMMON_IMPLEMENTATION -DU_I18N_IMPLEMENTATION -DUCONFIG_USE_LOCAL -DU_TOOLUTIL_IMPLEMENTATION -DNDEBUG -DWINVER=0x0600 -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0600 -DU_USE_STRTOD_L=0         -O2 -Wall  -mtune=generic -c stri_container_listint.cpp -o stri_container_listint.o
C:/Rtools/mingw_32/bin/g++  -std=gnu++11 -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-36~1.2/include" -DNDEBUG -I. -Iicu61/ -Iicu61/unicode -Iicu61/common -Iicu61/i18n -DU_STATIC_IMPLEMENTATION -DU_COMMON_IMPLEMENTATION -DU_I18N_IMPLEMENTATION -DUCONFIG_USE_LOCAL -DU_TOOLUTIL_IMPLEMENTATION -DNDEBUG -DWINVER=0x0600 -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0600 -DU_USE_STRTOD_L=0         -O2 -Wall  -mtune=generic -c stri_search_class_locate.cpp -o stri_search_class_locate.o
C:/Rtools/mingw_32/bin/g++  -std=gnu++11 -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-36~1.2/include" -DNDEBUG -I. -Iicu61/ -Iicu61/unicode -Iicu61/common -Iicu61/i18n -DU_STATIC_IMPLEMENTATION -DU_COMMON_IMPLEMENTATION -DU_I18N_IMPLEMENTATION -DUCONFIG_USE_LOCAL -DU_TOOLUTIL_IMPLEMENTATION -DNDEBUG -DWINVER=0x0600 -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0600 -DU_USE_STRTOD_L=0         -O2 -Wall  -mtune=generic -c stri_TODO_justify.cpp -o stri_TODO_justify.o
C:/Rtools/mingw_32/bin/g++  -std=gnu++11 -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-36~1.2/include" -DNDEBUG -I. -Iicu61/ -Iicu61/unicode -Iicu61/common -Iicu61/i18n -DU_STATIC_IMPLEMENTATION -DU_COMMON_IMPLEMENTATION -DU_I18N_IMPLEMENTATION -DUCONFIG_USE_LOCAL -DU_TOOLUTIL_IMPLEMENTATION -DNDEBUG -DWINVER=0x0600 -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0600 -DU_USE_STRTOD_L=0         -O2 -Wall  -mtune=generic -c stri_search_coll_extract.cpp -o stri_search_coll_extract.o
C:/Rtools/mingw_32/bin/g++  -std=gnu++11 -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-36~1.2/include" -DNDEBUG -I. -Iicu61/ -Iicu61/unicode -Iicu61/common -Iicu61/i18n -DU_STATIC_IMPLEMENTATION -DU_COMMON_IMPLEMENTATION -DU_I18N_IMPLEMENTATION -DUCONFIG_USE_LOCAL -DU_TOOLUTIL_IMPLEMENTATION -DNDEBUG -DWINVER=0x0600 -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0600 -DU_USE_STRTOD_L=0         -O2 -Wall  -mtune=generic -c stri_encoding_conversion.cpp -o stri_encoding_conversion.o
C:/Rtools/mingw_32/bin/g++  -std=gnu++11 -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-36~1.2/include" -DNDEBUG -I. -Iicu61/ -Iicu61/unicode -Iicu61/common -Iicu61/i18n -DU_STATIC_IMPLEMENTATION -DU_COMMON_IMPLEMENTATION -DU_I18N_IMPLEMENTATION -DUCONFIG_USE_LOCAL -DU_TOOLUTIL_IMPLEMENTATION -DNDEBUG -DWINVER=0x0600 -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0600 -DU_USE_STRTOD_L=0         -O2 -Wall  -mtune=generic -c stri_stats.cpp -o stri_stats.o
C:/Rtools/mingw_32/bin/g++  -std=gnu++11 -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-36~1.2/include" -DNDEBUG -I. -Iicu61/ -Iicu61/unicode -Iicu61/common -Iicu61/i18n -DU_STATIC_IMPLEMENTATION -DU_COMMON_IMPLEMENTATION -DU_I18N_IMPLEMENTATION -DUCONFIG_USE_LOCAL -DU_TOOLUTIL_IMPLEMENTATION -DNDEBUG -DWINVER=0x0600 -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0600 -DU_USE_STRTOD_L=0         -O2 -Wall  -mtune=generic -c stri_search_coll_replace.cpp -o stri_search_coll_replace.o
C:/Rtools/mingw_32/bin/g++  -std=gnu++11 -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-36~1.2/include" -DNDEBUG -I. -Iicu61/ -Iicu61/unicode -Iicu61/common -Iicu61/i18n -DU_STATIC_IMPLEMENTATION -DU_COMMON_IMPLEMENTATION -DU_I18N_IMPLEMENTATION -DUCONFIG_USE_LOCAL -DU_TOOLUTIL_IMPLEMENTATION -DNDEBUG -DWINVER=0x0600 -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0600 -DU_USE_STRTOD_L=0         -O2 -Wall  -mtune=generic -c stri_utils.cpp -o stri_utils.o
C:/Rtools/mingw_32/bin/g++  -std=gnu++11 -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-36~1.2/include" -DNDEBUG -I. -Iicu61/ -Iicu61/unicode -Iicu61/common -Iicu61/i18n -DU_STATIC_IMPLEMENTATION -DU_COMMON_IMPLEMENTATION -DU_I18N_IMPLEMENTATION -DUCONFIG_USE_LOCAL -DU_TOOLUTIL_IMPLEMENTATION -DNDEBUG -DWINVER=0x0600 -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0600 -DU_USE_STRTOD_L=0         -O2 -Wall  -mtune=generic -c stri_search_class_subset.cpp -o stri_search_class_subset.o
C:/Rtools/mingw_32/bin/g++  -std=gnu++11 -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-36~1.2/include" -DNDEBUG -I. -Iicu61/ -Iicu61/unicode -Iicu61/common -Iicu61/i18n -DU_STATIC_IMPLEMENTATION -DU_COMMON_IMPLEMENTATION -DU_I18N_IMPLEMENTATION -DUCONFIG_USE_LOCAL -DU_TOOLUTIL_IMPLEMENTATION -DNDEBUG -DWINVER=0x0600 -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0600 -DU_USE_STRTOD_L=0         -O2 -Wall  -mtune=generic -c stri_container_utf8_indexable.cpp -o stri_container_utf8_indexable.o
C:/Rtools/mingw_32/bin/g++  -std=gnu++11 -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-36~1.2/include" -DNDEBUG -I. -Iicu61/ -Iicu61/unicode -Iicu61/common -Iicu61/i18n -DU_STATIC_IMPLEMENTATION -DU_COMMON_IMPLEMENTATION -DU_I18N_IMPLEMENTATION -DUCONFIG_USE_LOCAL -DU_TOOLUTIL_IMPLEMENTATION -DNDEBUG -DWINVER=0x0600 -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0600 -DU_USE_STRTOD_L=0         -O2 -Wall  -mtune=generic -c stri_time_symbols.cpp -o stri_time_symbols.o
C:/Rtools/mingw_32/bin/g++  -std=gnu++11 -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-36~1.2/include" -DNDEBUG -I. -Iicu61/ -Iicu61/unicode -Iicu61/common -Iicu61/i18n -DU_STATIC_IMPLEMENTATION -DU_COMMON_IMPLEMENTATION -DU_I18N_IMPLEMENTATION -DUCONFIG_USE_LOCAL -DU_TOOLUTIL_IMPLEMENTATION -DNDEBUG -DWINVER=0x0600 -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0600 -DU_USE_STRTOD_L=0         -O2 -Wall  -mtune=generic -c stri_search_regex_extract.cpp -o stri_search_regex_extract.o
C:/Rtools/mingw_32/bin/g++  -std=gnu++11 -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-36~1.2/include" -DNDEBUG -I. -Iicu61/ -Iicu61/unicode -Iicu61/common -Iicu61/i18n -DU_STATIC_IMPLEMENTATION -DU_COMMON_IMPLEMENTATION -DU_I18N_IMPLEMENTATION -DUCONFIG_USE_LOCAL -DU_TOOLUTIL_IMPLEMENTATION -DNDEBUG -DWINVER=0x0600 -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0600 -DU_USE_STRTOD_L=0         -O2 -Wall  -mtune=generic -c stri_search_class_split.cpp -o stri_search_class_split.o
C:/Rtools/mingw_32/bin/g++  -std=gnu++11 -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-36~1.2/include" -DNDEBUG -I. -Iicu61/ -Iicu61/unicode -Iicu61/common -Iicu61/i18n -DU_STATIC_IMPLEMENTATION -DU_COMMON_IMPLEMENTATION -DU_I18N_IMPLEMENTATION -DUCONFIG_USE_LOCAL -DU_TOOLUTIL_IMPLEMENTATION -DNDEBUG -DWINVER=0x0600 -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0600 -DU_USE_STRTOD_L=0         -O2 -Wall  -mtune=generic -c stri_search_fixed_replace.cpp -o stri_search_fixed_replace.o
C:/Rtools/mingw_32/bin/g++  -std=gnu++11 -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-36~1.2/include" -DNDEBUG -I. -Iicu61/ -Iicu61/unicode -Iicu61/common -Iicu61/i18n -DU_STATIC_IMPLEMENTATION -DU_COMMON_IMPLEMENTATION -DU_I18N_IMPLEMENTATION -DUCONFIG_USE_LOCAL -DU_TOOLUTIL_IMPLEMENTATION -DNDEBUG -DWINVER=0x0600 -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0600 -DU_USE_STRTOD_L=0         -O2 -Wall  -mtune=generic -c stri_brkiter.cpp -o stri_brkiter.o
C:/Rtools/mingw_32/bin/g++  -std=gnu++11 -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-36~1.2/include" -DNDEBUG -I. -Iicu61/ -Iicu61/unicode -Iicu61/common -Iicu61/i18n -DU_STATIC_IMPLEMENTATION -DU_COMMON_IMPLEMENTATION -DU_I18N_IMPLEMENTATION -DUCONFIG_USE_LOCAL -DU_TOOLUTIL_IMPLEMENTATION -DNDEBUG -DWINVER=0x0600 -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0600 -DU_USE_STRTOD_L=0         -O2 -Wall  -mtune=generic -c stri_prepare_arg.cpp -o stri_prepare_arg.o
C:/Rtools/mingw_32/bin/g++  -std=gnu++11 -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-36~1.2/include" -DNDEBUG -I. -Iicu61/ -Iicu61/unicode -Iicu61/common -Iicu61/i18n -DU_STATIC_IMPLEMENTATION -DU_COMMON_IMPLEMENTATION -DU_I18N_IMPLEMENTATION -DUCONFIG_USE_LOCAL -DU_TOOLUTIL_IMPLEMENTATION -DNDEBUG -DWINVER=0x0600 -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0600 -DU_USE_STRTOD_L=0         -O2 -Wall  -mtune=generic -c stri_TODO_splitpos.cpp -o stri_TODO_splitpos.o
C:/Rtools/mingw_32/bin/g++  -std=gnu++11 -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-36~1.2/include" -DNDEBUG -I. -Iicu61/ -Iicu61/unicode -Iicu61/common -Iicu61/i18n -DU_STATIC_IMPLEMENTATION -DU_COMMON_IMPLEMENTATION -DU_I18N_IMPLEMENTATION -DUCONFIG_USE_LOCAL -DU_TOOLUTIL_IMPLEMENTATION -DNDEBUG -DWINVER=0x0600 -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0600 -DU_USE_STRTOD_L=0         -O2 -Wall  -mtune=generic -c stri_search_regex_count.cpp -o stri_search_regex_count.o
C:/Rtools/mingw_32/bin/g++  -std=gnu++11 -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-36~1.2/include" -DNDEBUG -I. -Iicu61/ -Iicu61/unicode -Iicu61/common -Iicu61/i18n -DU_STATIC_IMPLEMENTATION -DU_COMMON_IMPLEMENTATION -DU_I18N_IMPLEMENTATION -DUCONFIG_USE_LOCAL -DU_TOOLUTIL_IMPLEMENTATION -DNDEBUG -DWINVER=0x0600 -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0600 -DU_USE_STRTOD_L=0         -O2 -Wall  -mtune=generic -c stri_trans_other.cpp -o stri_trans_other.o
C:/Rtools/mingw_32/bin/g++  -std=gnu++11 -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-36~1.2/include" -DNDEBUG -I. -Iicu61/ -Iicu61/unicode -Iicu61/common -Iicu61/i18n -DU_STATIC_IMPLEMENTATION -DU_COMMON_IMPLEMENTATION -DU_I18N_IMPLEMENTATION -DUCONFIG_USE_LOCAL -DU_TOOLUTIL_IMPLEMENTATION -DNDEBUG -DWINVER=0x0600 -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0600 -DU_USE_STRTOD_L=0         -O2 -Wall  -mtune=generic -c stri_search_regex_replace.cpp -o stri_search_regex_replace.o
C:/Rtools/mingw_32/bin/g++  -std=gnu++11 -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-36~1.2/include" -DNDEBUG -I. -Iicu61/ -Iicu61/unicode -Iicu61/common -Iicu61/i18n -DU_STATIC_IMPLEMENTATION -DU_COMMON_IMPLEMENTATION -DU_I18N_IMPLEMENTATION -DUCONFIG_USE_LOCAL -DU_TOOLUTIL_IMPLEMENTATION -DNDEBUG -DWINVER=0x0600 -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0600 -DU_USE_STRTOD_L=0         -O2 -Wall  -mtune=generic -c stri_search_other_split.cpp -o stri_search_other_split.o
C:/Rtools/mingw_32/bin/g++  -std=gnu++11 -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-36~1.2/include" -DNDEBUG -I. -Iicu61/ -Iicu61/unicode -Iicu61/common -Iicu61/i18n -DU_STATIC_IMPLEMENTATION -DU_COMMON_IMPLEMENTATION -DU_I18N_IMPLEMENTATION -DUCONFIG_USE_LOCAL -DU_TOOLUTIL_IMPLEMENTATION -DNDEBUG -DWINVER=0x0600 -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0600 -DU_USE_STRTOD_L=0         -O2 -Wall  -mtune=generic -c stri_container_base.cpp -o stri_container_base.o
C:/Rtools/mingw_32/bin/g++  -std=gnu++11 -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-36~1.2/include" -DNDEBUG -I. -Iicu61/ -Iicu61/unicode -Iicu61/common -Iicu61/i18n -DU_STATIC_IMPLEMENTATION -DU_COMMON_IMPLEMENTATION -DU_I18N_IMPLEMENTATION -DUCONFIG_USE_LOCAL -DU_TOOLUTIL_IMPLEMENTATION -DNDEBUG -DWINVER=0x0600 -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0600 -DU_USE_STRTOD_L=0         -O2 -Wall  -mtune=generic -c stri_search_boundaries_count.cpp -o stri_search_boundaries_count.o
C:/Rtools/mingw_32/bin/g++  -std=gnu++11 -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-36~1.2/include" -DNDEBUG -I. -Iicu61/ -Iicu61/unicode -Iicu61/common -Iicu61/i18n -DU_STATIC_IMPLEMENTATION -DU_COMMON_IMPLEMENTATION -DU_I18N_IMPLEMENTATION -DUCONFIG_USE_LOCAL -DU_TOOLUTIL_IMPLEMENTATION -DNDEBUG -DWINVER=0x0600 -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0600 -DU_USE_STRTOD_L=0         -O2 -Wall  -mtune=generic -c stri_container_listraw.cpp -o stri_container_listraw.o
C:/Rtools/mingw_32/bin/g++  -std=gnu++11 -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-36~1.2/include" -DNDEBUG -I. -Iicu61/ -Iicu61/unicode -Iicu61/common -Iicu61/i18n -DU_STATIC_IMPLEMENTATION -DU_COMMON_IMPLEMENTATION -DU_I18N_IMPLEMENTATION -DUCONFIG_USE_LOCAL -DU_TOOLUTIL_IMPLEMENTATION -DNDEBUG -DWINVER=0x0600 -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0600 -DU_USE_STRTOD_L=0         -O2 -Wall  -mtune=generic -c stri_search_coll_detect.cpp -o stri_search_coll_detect.o
C:/Rtools/mingw_32/bin/g++  -std=gnu++11 -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-36~1.2/include" -DNDEBUG -I. -Iicu61/ -Iicu61/unicode -Iicu61/common -Iicu61/i18n -DU_STATIC_IMPLEMENTATION -DU_COMMON_IMPLEMENTATION -DU_I18N_IMPLEMENTATION -DUCONFIG_USE_LOCAL -DU_TOOLUTIL_IMPLEMENTATION -DNDEBUG -DWINVER=0x0600 -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0600 -DU_USE_STRTOD_L=0         -O2 -Wall  -mtune=generic -c stri_escape.cpp -o stri_escape.o
C:/Rtools/mingw_32/bin/g++  -std=gnu++11 -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-36~1.2/include" -DNDEBUG -I. -Iicu61/ -Iicu61/unicode -Iicu61/common -Iicu61/i18n -DU_STATIC_IMPLEMENTATION -DU_COMMON_IMPLEMENTATION -DU_I18N_IMPLEMENTATION -DUCONFIG_USE_LOCAL -DU_TOOLUTIL_IMPLEMENTATION -DNDEBUG -DWINVER=0x0600 -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0600 -DU_USE_STRTOD_L=0         -O2 -Wall  -mtune=generic -c stri_test.cpp -o stri_test.o
C:/Rtools/mingw_32/bin/g++  -std=gnu++11 -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-36~1.2/include" -DNDEBUG -I. -Iicu61/ -Iicu61/unicode -Iicu61/common -Iicu61/i18n -DU_STATIC_IMPLEMENTATION -DU_COMMON_IMPLEMENTATION -DU_I18N_IMPLEMENTATION -DUCONFIG_USE_LOCAL -DU_TOOLUTIL_IMPLEMENTATION -DNDEBUG -DWINVER=0x0600 -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0600 -DU_USE_STRTOD_L=0         -O2 -Wall  -mtune=generic -c stri_ICU_settings.cpp -o stri_ICU_settings.o
C:/Rtools/mingw_32/bin/g++  -std=gnu++11 -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-36~1.2/include" -DNDEBUG -I. -Iicu61/ -Iicu61/unicode -Iicu61/common -Iicu61/i18n -DU_STATIC_IMPLEMENTATION -DU_COMMON_IMPLEMENTATION -DU_I18N_IMPLEMENTATION -DUCONFIG_USE_LOCAL -DU_TOOLUTIL_IMPLEMENTATION -DNDEBUG -DWINVER=0x0600 -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0600 -DU_USE_STRTOD_L=0         -O2 -Wall  -mtune=generic -c stri_search_boundaries_locate.cpp -o stri_search_boundaries_locate.o
C:/Rtools/mingw_32/bin/g++  -std=gnu++11 -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-36~1.2/include" -DNDEBUG -I. -Iicu61/ -Iicu61/unicode -Iicu61/common -Iicu61/i18n -DU_STATIC_IMPLEMENTATION -DU_COMMON_IMPLEMENTATION -DU_I18N_IMPLEMENTATION -DUCONFIG_USE_LOCAL -DU_TOOLUTIL_IMPLEMENTATION -DNDEBUG -DWINVER=0x0600 -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0600 -DU_USE_STRTOD_L=0         -O2 -Wall  -mtune=generic -c stri_encoding_management.cpp -o stri_encoding_management.o
C:/Rtools/mingw_32/bin/g++  -std=gnu++11 -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-36~1.2/include" -DNDEBUG -I. -Iicu61/ -Iicu61/unicode -Iicu61/common -Iicu61/i18n -DU_STATIC_IMPLEMENTATION -DU_COMMON_IMPLEMENTATION -DU_I18N_IMPLEMENTATION -DUCONFIG_USE_LOCAL -DU_TOOLUTIL_IMPLEMENTATION -DNDEBUG -DWINVER=0x0600 -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0600 -DU_USE_STRTOD_L=0         -O2 -Wall  -mtune=generic -c stri_reverse.cpp -o stri_reverse.o
C:/Rtools/mingw_32/bin/g++  -std=gnu++11 -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-36~1.2/include" -DNDEBUG -I. -Iicu61/ -Iicu61/unicode -Iicu61/common -Iicu61/i18n -DU_STATIC_IMPLEMENTATION -DU_COMMON_IMPLEMENTATION -DU_I18N_IMPLEMENTATION -DUCONFIG_USE_LOCAL -DU_TOOLUTIL_IMPLEMENTATION -DNDEBUG -DWINVER=0x0600 -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0600 -DU_USE_STRTOD_L=0         -O2 -Wall  -mtune=generic -c stri_encoding_detection.cpp -o stri_encoding_detection.o
C:/Rtools/mingw_32/bin/g++  -std=gnu++11 -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-36~1.2/include" -DNDEBUG -I. -Iicu61/ -Iicu61/unicode -Iicu61/common -Iicu61/i18n -DU_STATIC_IMPLEMENTATION -DU_COMMON_IMPLEMENTATION -DU_I18N_IMPLEMENTATION -DUCONFIG_USE_LOCAL -DU_TOOLUTIL_IMPLEMENTATION -DNDEBUG -DWINVER=0x0600 -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0600 -DU_USE_STRTOD_L=0         -O2 -Wall  -mtune=generic -c stri_container_usearch.cpp -o stri_container_usearch.o
C:/Rtools/mingw_32/bin/g++  -std=gnu++11 -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-36~1.2/include" -DNDEBUG -I. -Iicu61/ -Iicu61/unicode -Iicu61/common -Iicu61/i18n -DU_STATIC_IMPLEMENTATION -DU_COMMON_IMPLEMENTATION -DU_I18N_IMPLEMENTATION -DUCONFIG_USE_LOCAL -DU_TOOLUTIL_IMPLEMENTATION -DNDEBUG -DWINVER=0x0600 -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0600 -DU_USE_STRTOD_L=0         -O2 -Wall  -mtune=generic -c stri_search_regex_match.cpp -o stri_search_regex_match.o
C:/Rtools/mingw_32/bin/g++  -std=gnu++11 -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-36~1.2/include" -DNDEBUG -I. -Iicu61/ -Iicu61/unicode -Iicu61/common -Iicu61/i18n -DU_STATIC_IMPLEMENTATION -DU_COMMON_IMPLEMENTATION -DU_I18N_IMPLEMENTATION -DUCONFIG_USE_LOCAL -DU_TOOLUTIL_IMPLEMENTATION -DNDEBUG -DWINVER=0x0600 -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0600 -DU_USE_STRTOD_L=0         -O2 -Wall  -mtune=generic -c stri_search_fixed_detect.cpp -o stri_search_fixed_detect.o
C:/Rtools/mingw_32/bin/g++  -std=gnu++11 -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-36~1.2/include" -DNDEBUG -I. -Iicu61/ -Iicu61/unicode -Iicu61/common -Iicu61/i18n -DU_STATIC_IMPLEMENTATION -DU_COMMON_IMPLEMENTATION -DU_I18N_IMPLEMENTATION -DUCONFIG_USE_LOCAL -DU_TOOLUTIL_IMPLEMENTATION -DNDEBUG -DWINVER=0x0600 -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0600 -DU_USE_STRTOD_L=0         -O2 -Wall  -mtune=generic -c stri_trans_transliterate.cpp -o stri_trans_transliterate.o
C:/Rtools/mingw_32/bin/g++  -std=gnu++11 -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-36~1.2/include" -DNDEBUG -I. -Iicu61/ -Iicu61/unicode -Iicu61/common -Iicu61/i18n -DU_STATIC_IMPLEMENTATION -DU_COMMON_IMPLEMENTATION -DU_I18N_IMPLEMENTATION -DUCONFIG_USE_LOCAL -DU_TOOLUTIL_IMPLEMENTATION -DNDEBUG -DWINVER=0x0600 -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0600 -DU_USE_STRTOD_L=0         -O2 -Wall  -mtune=generic -c stri_search_regex_detect.cpp -o stri_search_regex_detect.o
C:/Rtools/mingw_32/bin/g++  -std=gnu++11 -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-36~1.2/include" -DNDEBUG -I. -Iicu61/ -Iicu61/unicode -Iicu61/common -Iicu61/i18n -DU_STATIC_IMPLEMENTATION -DU_COMMON_IMPLEMENTATION -DU_I18N_IMPLEMENTATION -DUCONFIG_USE_LOCAL -DU_TOOLUTIL_IMPLEMENTATION -DNDEBUG -DWINVER=0x0600 -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0600 -DU_USE_STRTOD_L=0         -O2 -Wall  -mtune=generic -c stri_exception.cpp -o stri_exception.o
C:/Rtools/mingw_32/bin/g++  -std=gnu++11 -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-36~1.2/include" -DNDEBUG -I. -Iicu61/ -Iicu61/unicode -Iicu61/common -Iicu61/i18n -DU_STATIC_IMPLEMENTATION -DU_COMMON_IMPLEMENTATION -DU_I18N_IMPLEMENTATION -DUCONFIG_USE_LOCAL -DU_TOOLUTIL_IMPLEMENTATION -DNDEBUG -DWINVER=0x0600 -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0600 -DU_USE_STRTOD_L=0         -O2 -Wall  -mtune=generic -c stri_length.cpp -o stri_length.o
C:/Rtools/mingw_32/bin/g++  -std=gnu++11 -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-36~1.2/include" -DNDEBUG -I. -Iicu61/ -Iicu61/unicode -Iicu61/common -Iicu61/i18n -DU_STATIC_IMPLEMENTATION -DU_COMMON_IMPLEMENTATION -DU_I18N_IMPLEMENTATION -DUCONFIG_USE_LOCAL -DU_TOOLUTIL_IMPLEMENTATION -DNDEBUG -DWINVER=0x0600 -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0600 -DU_USE_STRTOD_L=0         -O2 -Wall  -mtune=generic -c stri_search_class_extract.cpp -o stri_search_class_extract.o
C:/Rtools/mingw_32/bin/g++  -std=gnu++11 -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-36~1.2/include" -DNDEBUG -I. -Iicu61/ -Iicu61/unicode -Iicu61/common -Iicu61/i18n -DU_STATIC_IMPLEMENTATION -DU_COMMON_IMPLEMENTATION -DU_I18N_IMPLEMENTATION -DUCONFIG_USE_LOCAL -DU_TOOLUTIL_IMPLEMENTATION -DNDEBUG -DWINVER=0x0600 -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0600 -DU_USE_STRTOD_L=0         -O2 -Wall  -mtune=generic -c stri_TODO_uchar.cpp -o stri_TODO_uchar.o
C:/Rtools/mingw_32/bin/g++  -std=gnu++11 -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-36~1.2/include" -DNDEBUG -I. -Iicu61/ -Iicu61/unicode -Iicu61/common -Iicu61/i18n -DU_STATIC_IMPLEMENTATION -DU_COMMON_IMPLEMENTATION -DU_I18N_IMPLEMENTATION -DUCONFIG_USE_LOCAL -DU_TOOLUTIL_IMPLEMENTATION -DNDEBUG -DWINVER=0x0600 -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0600 -DU_USE_STRTOD_L=0         -O2 -Wall  -mtune=generic -c stri_time_format.cpp -o stri_time_format.o
C:/Rtools/mingw_32/bin/g++  -std=gnu++11 -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-36~1.2/include" -DNDEBUG -I. -Iicu61/ -Iicu61/unicode -Iicu61/common -Iicu61/i18n -DU_STATIC_IMPLEMENTATION -DU_COMMON_IMPLEMENTATION -DU_I18N_IMPLEMENTATION -DUCONFIG_USE_LOCAL -DU_TOOLUTIL_IMPLEMENTATION -DNDEBUG -DWINVER=0x0600 -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0600 -DU_USE_STRTOD_L=0         -O2 -Wall  -mtune=generic -c stri_common.cpp -o stri_common.o
C:/Rtools/mingw_32/bin/g++  -std=gnu++11 -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-36~1.2/include" -DNDEBUG -I. -Iicu61/ -Iicu61/unicode -Iicu61/common -Iicu61/i18n -DU_STATIC_IMPLEMENTATION -DU_COMMON_IMPLEMENTATION -DU_I18N_IMPLEMENTATION -DUCONFIG_USE_LOCAL -DU_TOOLUTIL_IMPLEMENTATION -DNDEBUG -DWINVER=0x0600 -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0600 -DU_USE_STRTOD_L=0         -O2 -Wall  -mtune=generic -c stri_time_calendar.cpp -o stri_time_calendar.o
C:/Rtools/mingw_32/bin/g++  -std=gnu++11 -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-36~1.2/include" -DNDEBUG -I. -Iicu61/ -Iicu61/unicode -Iicu61/common -Iicu61/i18n -DU_STATIC_IMPLEMENTATION -DU_COMMON_IMPLEMENTATION -DU_I18N_IMPLEMENTATION -DUCONFIG_USE_LOCAL -DU_TOOLUTIL_IMPLEMENTATION -DNDEBUG -DWINVER=0x0600 -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0600 -DU_USE_STRTOD_L=0         -O2 -Wall  -mtune=generic -c stri_search_coll_locate.cpp -o stri_search_coll_locate.o
C:/Rtools/mingw_32/bin/g++  -std=gnu++11 -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-36~1.2/include" -DNDEBUG -I. -Iicu61/ -Iicu61/unicode -Iicu61/common -Iicu61/i18n -DU_STATIC_IMPLEMENTATION -DU_COMMON_IMPLEMENTATION -DU_I18N_IMPLEMENTATION -DUCONFIG_USE_LOCAL -DU_TOOLUTIL_IMPLEMENTATION -DNDEBUG -DWINVER=0x0600 -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0600 -DU_USE_STRTOD_L=0         -O2 -Wall  -mtune=generic -c stri_search_fixed_count.cpp -o stri_search_fixed_count.o
C:/Rtools/mingw_32/bin/g++  -std=gnu++11 -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-36~1.2/include" -DNDEBUG -I. -Iicu61/ -Iicu61/unicode -Iicu61/common -Iicu61/i18n -DU_STATIC_IMPLEMENTATION -DU_COMMON_IMPLEMENTATION -DU_I18N_IMPLEMENTATION -DUCONFIG_USE_LOCAL -DU_TOOLUTIL_IMPLEMENTATION -DNDEBUG -DWINVER=0x0600 -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0600 -DU_USE_STRTOD_L=0         -O2 -Wall  -mtune=generic -c stri_collator.cpp -o stri_collator.o
C:/Rtools/mingw_32/bin/g++  -std=gnu++11 -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-36~1.2/include" -DNDEBUG -I. -Iicu61/ -Iicu61/unicode -Iicu61/common -Iicu61/i18n -DU_STATIC_IMPLEMENTATION -DU_COMMON_IMPLEMENTATION -DU_I18N_IMPLEMENTATION -DUCONFIG_USE_LOCAL -DU_TOOLUTIL_IMPLEMENTATION -DNDEBUG -DWINVER=0x0600 -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0600 -DU_USE_STRTOD_L=0         -O2 -Wall  -mtune=generic -c stri_join.cpp -o stri_join.o
C:/Rtools/mingw_32/bin/g++  -std=gnu++11 -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-36~1.2/include" -DNDEBUG -I. -Iicu61/ -Iicu61/unicode -Iicu61/common -Iicu61/i18n -DU_STATIC_IMPLEMENTATION -DU_COMMON_IMPLEMENTATION -DU_I18N_IMPLEMENTATION -DUCONFIG_USE_LOCAL -DU_TOOLUTIL_IMPLEMENTATION -DNDEBUG -DWINVER=0x0600 -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0600 -DU_USE_STRTOD_L=0         -O2 -Wall  -mtune=generic -c stri_search_boundaries_split.cpp -o stri_search_boundaries_split.o
C:/Rtools/mingw_32/bin/g++  -std=gnu++11 -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-36~1.2/include" -DNDEBUG -I. -Iicu61/ -Iicu61/unicode -Iicu61/common -Iicu61/i18n -DU_STATIC_IMPLEMENTATION -DU_COMMON_IMPLEMENTATION -DU_I18N_IMPLEMENTATION -DUCONFIG_USE_LOCAL -DU_TOOLUTIL_IMPLEMENTATION -DNDEBUG -DWINVER=0x0600 -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0600 -DU_USE_STRTOD_L=0         -O2 -Wall  -mtune=generic -c stri_container_bytesearch.cpp -o stri_container_bytesearch.o
C:/Rtools/mingw_32/bin/g++  -std=gnu++11 -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-36~1.2/include" -DNDEBUG -I. -Iicu61/ -Iicu61/unicode -Iicu61/common -Iicu61/i18n -DU_STATIC_IMPLEMENTATION -DU_COMMON_IMPLEMENTATION -DU_I18N_IMPLEMENTATION -DUCONFIG_USE_LOCAL -DU_TOOLUTIL_IMPLEMENTATION -DNDEBUG -DWINVER=0x0600 -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0600 -DU_USE_STRTOD_L=0         -O2 -Wall  -mtune=generic -c stri_search_class_replace.cpp -o stri_search_class_replace.o
C:/Rtools/mingw_32/bin/g++  -std=gnu++11 -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-36~1.2/include" -DNDEBUG -I. -Iicu61/ -Iicu61/unicode -Iicu61/common -Iicu61/i18n -DU_STATIC_IMPLEMENTATION -DU_COMMON_IMPLEMENTATION -DU_I18N_IMPLEMENTATION -DUCONFIG_USE_LOCAL -DU_TOOLUTIL_IMPLEMENTATION -DNDEBUG -DWINVER=0x0600 -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0600 -DU_USE_STRTOD_L=0         -O2 -Wall  -mtune=generic -c stri_compare.cpp -o stri_compare.o
C:/Rtools/mingw_32/bin/g++  -std=gnu++11 -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-36~1.2/include" -DNDEBUG -I. -Iicu61/ -Iicu61/unicode -Iicu61/common -Iicu61/i18n -DU_STATIC_IMPLEMENTATION -DU_COMMON_IMPLEMENTATION -DU_I18N_IMPLEMENTATION -DUCONFIG_USE_LOCAL -DU_TOOLUTIL_IMPLEMENTATION -DNDEBUG -DWINVER=0x0600 -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0600 -DU_USE_STRTOD_L=0         -O2 -Wall  -mtune=generic -c stri_search_fixed_startsendswith.cpp -o stri_search_fixed_startsendswith.o
C:/Rtools/mingw_32/bin/g++  -std=gnu++11 -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-36~1.2/include" -DNDEBUG -I. -Iicu61/ -Iicu61/unicode -Iicu61/common -Iicu61/i18n -DU_STATIC_IMPLEMENTATION -DU_COMMON_IMPLEMENTATION -DU_I18N_IMPLEMENTATION -DUCONFIG_USE_LOCAL -DU_TOOLUTIL_IMPLEMENTATION -DNDEBUG -DWINVER=0x0600 -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0600 -DU_USE_STRTOD_L=0         -O2 -Wall  -mtune=generic -c stri_search_class_startsendswith.cpp -o stri_search_class_startsendswith.o
C:/Rtools/mingw_32/bin/g++  -std=gnu++11 -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-36~1.2/include" -DNDEBUG -I. -Iicu61/ -Iicu61/unicode -Iicu61/common -Iicu61/i18n -DU_STATIC_IMPLEMENTATION -DU_COMMON_IMPLEMENTATION -DU_I18N_IMPLEMENTATION -DUCONFIG_USE_LOCAL -DU_TOOLUTIL_IMPLEMENTATION -DNDEBUG -DWINVER=0x0600 -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0600 -DU_USE_STRTOD_L=0         -O2 -Wall  -mtune=generic -c stri_search_class_detect.cpp -o stri_search_class_detect.o
```

Comment: If you chose to install the binary version instead, it would be done much quicker. See `?install.packages` for `type=`, my guess from your output above is that your `getOption("pkgType")` is `"source"`, so you compile everything when you install. If you change that (or just one-time call `install.packages(..., type="binary")`, you'll get it faster. Alternatively, you can download the zip file from https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/stringi/index.html and `install.packages("path/to/stringi_1.5.3.zip")` and get the same effect.

Comment: wow. you are awesome. It worked. can you write as an answer? I can accept it

Comment: btw my `getOption("pkgType")` returns `both` as output

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Source installs are the most up-to-date, where binary packages may lag by "some time". This is reflected in your output, where your R-3.6 sees 1.4.6 as the most recent though 1.5.3 source is available.

Some ways around this:

1. `install.packages("stringi", type="binary")` should find the closest version and install it without needing to compile it.
2. Download one of the `.zip` files (since you're on windows) from the CRAN page for [`stringi`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/stringi/index.html) page and then use `install.packages("path/to/stringi_1.5.3.zip")`. **However**, they only have binary versions for R-4.0, not for R-3.6 ("r-oldrel"), so ... it may complain, or it may install and fail spectacularly when you most need the package in the future (and are on the plane without an internet connection).
3. According to a [blog post](https://blog.rstudio.com/2020/07/01/announcing-public-package-manager/) on RStudio, you can use their public CRAN-*like* mirror to install binary packages for: linux (not available on CRAN) and for older releases of R (also not available on CRAN).

In your case, since you said your `getOption("pkgType")` is `"both"`, that means *'use binary if available and current, otherwise try source'* (from `?install.packages`), which matches the 1.4.6-vs-1.5.3 issue I mentioned first.